# How to have Visual Studio generate a Win Forms app for .NET Framework 4.5?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, .net-framework-version

I have MS Visual Studio Community 2022. I called Create Project → Windows Forms application (.NET framework). On the next page I see list of Platforms. The list contains .NET Framework 3.5, 4.7.2.,  4.8, 4.8.1.
Is there a way to add .NET Framework 4.5 into this list? I have tried to install .NET Framework 4.5 on my computer, but the installer said that there is already new version of .NET Framework 4.5; and refused to install 4.5.